# How to validate dynamically created checkbox by name attribute using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am validating survey questions,it contains radio type questions and checkbox type question...radio type questions is working properly,and checkbox is not working...in name field i am passing question_id as name for radio button and question_id+option_id as name for checkbox...

if i put only question id for checkbox it is validating but i need to check multiple options...

//for radio

```
<input type="radio" class=" radio" name="31" value="101"   style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;">&nbsp;Good                                               
<input type="radio" class=" radio" name="31" value="102"   style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;">&nbsp;Average
```

//for checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="required check" id="20" name="20_85" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="85">&nbsp;Not good                                                
<input type="checkbox"  class="required check" id="20" name="20_84" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="84">&nbsp;Good
```

i need to validate this checkbox.

//jquery validation on click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(window).off("resize");
$(window).on("resize", function() {
var newHeight = $("body").outerHeight() + 20;
if($("html").outerHeight() > newHeight) {
 newHeight = $("html").outerHeight();
 }
 parent.postMessage(newHeight, '*');
 }).trigger("resize");
 var validationParameters = {
 rules: {
 mobileNumber1: {
 required: true,
 digits: true,
  rangelength: [10,10]
  }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  if($(element).prevAll("label:first").length > 0) {
  $(element).prevAll("label:first").after(error);
   }
 else {
$(element).parent().prevAll("label:first").after(error);
}
$(window).trigger("resize");
},
success: function(label) {
$(window).trigger("resize");
}
};
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) {
 validationParameters.onkeyup = function(element, event) { };
 validationParameters.focusInvalid = function(element, event) { };
 validationParameters.onfocusout = function(element, event) { };
 }
 $("#customerMakeReservation2Mobile").validate(validationParameters);
 $("#continueButton").click(function() {
 if($("#customerMakeReservation2Mobile").valid()) {
  var phone = $("#mobileNumber1").val();
  $("#phone1").val(phone.substr(0, 3));
  $("#phone2").val(phone.substr(3, 3));
  $("#phone3").val(phone.substr(6, 4));

 $("#customerMakeReservation2Mobile").submit();
 }
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to validate a checkbox? You cannot and must not have duplicate id's - they must be unique.

Comment: user survey feedback...user must select two checkbox answer

Comment: You CAN actually have duplicate ids but it makes no sense since you will only be able to retrieve one of them in your JavaScript code. Name (if an array) and class can be the same though which make sense if they're a natural collection. Then you can easily loop over them using jQuery.

Comment: ok....i will change id's like name...,then how can i validate that?

Comment: You didn't post the code for your `validate()` function. What is the validation logic ?? what do you want to do with those selectors ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u1oso78u/2/ @TCHdvlp

Comment: The only thing I can see here is that you are validating the mobileNumber... Is there any doc on the validation plugin you used for custom validation ?

Comment: yes...here i added that custom page https://jsfiddle.net/3tmruoaj/ @TCHdvlp

Comment: Sorry @FakkirmohamedSait, your code is literally terribly unreadable !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105567/discussion-between-fakkir-mohamed-sait-and-tchdvlp).